How can i cut the openings of a 3D scan in a resource friendly way?
I have to merge several 3D scans into one big model. Its a huge castle with a outside photoscan with a drone (20M vertex and 16K texture) and photoscans of the interiors (approx 50x 1-3M polygon) The model is already super resource intensive, using more than 40gb of RAM.
So i have to figure out a way to connect the interiors and the exteriors with cutting a doorway. Whith what kind of method can i achive this?
The blueis-purple object is the outer shell, the other colors are the interiors already positioned.




Hello, anything involving going into edit mode will be a pain and likely crash Blender. You can try using a boolean modifier. Another solution is to decimate your base meshes individually, you'll never have a smooth experience with such a dense mesh.

Hey, thanks for your comment. Yes, working with it in edit mode is very slow.
I tried the boolean modifier, but it does not work, becouse the scans have holes in it. If i apply boolean, the exact option is bugging( even if i check hole tolerant checkbox ), and the fast option is just simply not changing anything.
